# WordPress Gutenberg handling CSS in the editor

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've created my website that compiles my scss (boostrap, node_modules, my own custom css) to a single file. Now I'm wondering what would be the best way of styling gutenberg blocks in the editor?

I want to keep the responsive nature of my blocks from bootstrap and my styling what would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: This question should probably be on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com, which is why it's being down-voted. But you'll find this article really helpful in terms of how to enqueue your SASS for Gutenberg (and other things): https://www.billerickson.net/building-a-gutenberg-website/

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.That article really helped!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the CSS file for the front-end of your site to also apply to the block editor?

If so, that's as simple as adding `add_theme_support('editor-styles');` in your theme files (such as in functions.php).

I find it helpful to create a second block-editor stylesheet to use only in the editor. Sometimes I find the media query breakpoints are too different or just need to tweak the front-end styles a little for the editor. For that file, you can use `wp_enqueue_script()` on the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action hook so it applies only to the editor.